# Need to set a variable with "[]"

Tags: quoting, tcsh, variable

I have a tcsh script, in which I need to set a variable to this value defining my system type.

```
type=abc project=def sysname=["Linux"]
```

I tried various combinations to escape the `[` and `"` but have not been successful . I either get **Unmatched "** or, I am not able to echo the variable.

I tried the below code.

```
set systype = "type=abc project=def sysname=\[\"Linux\"\]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can guard the string using single quotes.

#### Example

*set*

```
$ set systype='type=abc project=def sysname=["Linux"]'
```

*echo*

```
$ echo "$systype"
type=abc project=def sysname=["Linux"]
```